# How to query for every manager born after certain date in WHERE clause - SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a table called 'managers' and in it is a column called 'birth_date' with the data type of DATE. I'm trying to query for every manager in my *managers* table who was born before 1973 with a WHERE clause.
I thought this was the proper syntax, but it's not working:

```
SELECT birth_date FROM managers
WHERE birth_date < '1973'
```

Comment: You don't really want `birth_date < '1973'`. What you want is that the year of your date is less than the integer value of 1973. Then you should fix your query as follows: `SELECT birth_date FROM managers WHERE YEAR(birth_date) < 1973`

Comment: Note: mysql <> postgresql. Don't dbms spam: you'll get the attention of professionals who may provide you a solution that doesn't work for your real dbms and you'll be wasting both yours and theirs time.

Comment: To make this a more complete question, please provide some sample `birth_date` data from the `managers` table (this will also allow us to see the type of field this is [unix timestamp? datetime? string?]), and explain which rows should and should not be selected from your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1973 is not a valid date, you must pass a valid format, e.g.

```
SELECT birth_date 
FROM managers
WHERE birth_date < DATE('1973-01-01')
```